# issue a terminal command from an sqlserver to a windows machine

Tags: sql-server, windows, cmd, telnet, psexec

I have an **sqlserver**, say serverA, and a **windows machine**, say machineA.

I have a testrun.**bat** file in machineA that I need to run after a certain process is finished in serverA.

I have learned that I can use **PSExec** to issue a terminal command from serverA to machineA.

I'm just wondering if I can do this using Microsoft Telnet service? Because I am not sure if PSExec wiil be allowed to be installed in serverA because of certain security concerns.

Basically, I'm just looking for plan B in case I cannot use PSExec. Another way I realized that I can use is Microsoft telnet but I am not sure how or if it is even possible.

Additional details:

- serverA runs Windows Server 2012
- machine A runs Windows 7 Enterprise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use native `wmic` command.

```dos
wmic /user:<username> /password:<password> /node:<machine> process call create "cmd /c c:\somewhere\myBatchFile.cmd"
```

Remember that

- As the process is created in the remote machine, the batch file must exist on it and the path has to reflect the location in the remote machine
- The process is started under the indicated user, probably in a separate session. You will probably not see the batch file running, check the processes list
- If the path to the batch file include spaces, you will need to quote it as

```dos
 wmic ... call create "cmd /c \"c:\some where\My Batch.cmd\""
```

Comment: Hi @MC ND! Thank you for your answer but I'm trying this now, but I'm getting access is denied. do I have to be an Administrator of the machine I am accessing via wmic?

Comment: Hi @MC ND! I tried using an administrator account of the target machine to issue the wmic command and it works. However, my batch file actually writes a log to a text file but it doesn't write to a file when I run the batch file using wmic. It works fine though if I run the batch file locally on the target machine...

Comment: @Krish, for the access rights, you could read [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4f33837b-1cb1-4648-85b1-3ba87cbfe93e/wmi-remote-access-denied?forum=winserverManagement) how to handle it and adapt to your needs. For the log file, remember you are executing it in the remote machine, with a different account and a different default active directory.

Comment: Hi @MC ND! For the log file, I still can't get to have the batch file write to a file. I posted another post about it here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607634/which-account-is-used-when-executing-xp-cmdshell-wmic-java-jar). Can you take a look and give some insights? I really think the permission issue arises when I use wmic command.